# Separating WPF dialogs from data class

Tags: wpf, ado.net, refactoring, modal-dialog

I have a small .NET 4 program using WPF, which heavily uses ADO.NET.  I am having to refactor the code now to separate the SQL data access/processing from the "main window" WPF window. Currently, there is a lot of data integrity checking in the DataSet-building code, which (potentially) throws up quite a few modal warning dialogs (like using MessageBox.Show()). I would like to "do the right thing" here and separate the data processing from the window displaying. (Or is that not so bad to have that modal dialog pop up from a purely "number-crunching class"?) How should I be doing this? Any pointers to articles/concepts would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: It may be a point of opinion on my part, but my *feeling* is that the general consensus is that libraries, helper classes, and "data models" should never produce modal dialogues... or any visual artifacts.  Only the display code should do that.  So, IMHO, you're on the right track.  The non-UI code should generate exceptions, which the display code should catch and transform into dialogue calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using data objects or just datasets?  If you're using data objects, use `IDataErrorInfo` to implement the validation, then enable validation in your WPF controls instead of popping up message boxes.  Here's a good article about datasets and validation  - [Displaying Data Validation Messages in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/06/27/displaying-data-validation-messages-in-wpf.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess I did not explain myself well. The "validation" that I need to happen requires complex calculations of existing tables - not something that a user might key in at a PC, so I can't just check table cells as they are created. After doing some more research what I really probably need is a MVVM setup.

Comment: Which is a special case of what I was proposing. By implementing an MVVM solution you're moving  from using datasets to using actual data objects, which you can then add your validation code to.